How can i use pip command correctly in Python?
So, I recently installed Python in my system and followed all the path that it gave. But still, I'm stcuk here, what should i do, please help me.
I think that i might have missed any thing in between the process that i cant recall, I was trying to install flask in my pc, but failed miserably

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

You're trying to run a shell command from Python. Type quit() to leave Python, then you can py -m pip install whatever. See https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

pip install flask
just this simple and easy if not works check whether python is installed or not.
python3 --version //OR// python --version
Install Python first
Visit Download Python
if error still persist, then update path variable in environment.

open cmd or related terminal, make sure your python is installed
do pip install Flask

There are several ways to install flask few ways worked for me are

Using it with python3 -m command

python3 -m pip install flask


Directly using it pip

pip install flask


Using python virtual environment

python3 -m venv flaskenv
source flaskenv/bin/activate
pip install flask

Make sure you have python installed in your pc
